# Prevent ionization of electrons within a gas

Tags: plasma-physics

Suppose we have a vacuum tube, inside it there is a beam of electrons traveling inside a gas (argon), according to the ionization energy of the argon it must not exceed the energy of K = e * 15.76V, with 'e' the charge of the electron, so if I get the electrons to travel at a speed less than that energy, is it possible to prevent the electrons from ionizing?

Comment: How much argon? There is a bit of contradiction between having a vacuum tube and having it full of argon.

Comment: Also note that the electron beam is not *monochromatic*- the electrons in the beam exhibit a distribution of energies.

Comment: I recommend you try this experiment with *jargon* gas instead. If you take a hit of jargon, you can speak in scientific tongues.

Comment: @JonCuster Phototubes use the photoelectric effect to produce a current, this have a inside a vacuum tube, the gas is used to ionize the gas (with the electrons) and therefore produce more electrons and therefore more current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the pressure of argon is so high, that the speed of e- between two collisions is less than the ionization energy, tree will not be any ionization